# How to fix problem with running my Flutter app on Redmi A1+?

Tags: flutter

Can't run app on Xiaomi Redmi A1+. Just white sceen. On all other smarthones work ok!

In debug mode next error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on 220733SFG in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 7170): Attaching Geolocator to activity
D/FlutterGeolocator( 7170): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 7170): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 7170): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator( 7170): Initializing Geolocator services
D/FlutterGeolocator( 7170): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53125/PnLEctRPbCw=/ws
Syncing files to device 220733SFG...
W/isarworker( 7170): type=1400 audit(0.0:1125): avc: denied { search } for name="vendor" dev="tmpfs" ino=7352 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c177,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mnt_vendor_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=ru.ivjh.esc.esc_driver
W/isarworker( 7170): type=1400 audit(0.0:1126): avc: denied { search } for name="vendor" dev="tmpfs" ino=7352 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c177,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mnt_vendor_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=ru.ivjh.esc.esc_driver
W/isarworker( 7170): type=1400 audit(0.0:1127): avc: denied { search } for name="vendor" dev="tmpfs" ino=7352 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c177,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mnt_vendor_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=ru.ivjh.esc.esc_driver
W/isarworker( 7170): type=1400 audit(0.0:1128): avc: denied { search } for name="vendor" dev="tmpfs" ino=7352 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c177,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mnt_vendor_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=ru.ivjh.esc.esc_driver
W/isarworker( 7170): type=1400 audit(0.0:1129): avc: denied { search } for name="vendor" dev="tmpfs" ino=7352 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c177,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mnt_vendor_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=ru.ivjh.esc.esc_driver
W/isarworker( 7170): type=1400 audit(0.0:1130): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/metadata" dev="mmcblk0p13" ino=2 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c177,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:metadata_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=ru.ivjh.esc.esc_driver
W/isarworker( 7170): type=1400 audit(0.0:1131): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/linkerconfig" dev="tmpfs" ino=9277 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c177,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:linkerconfig_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=ru.ivjh.esc.esc_driver
E/flutter ( 7170): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: IsarError: Cannot open Environment: MdbxError (12): Out of memory
E/flutter ( 7170): 
D/ProfileInstaller( 7170): Installing profile for ru.ivjh.esc.esc_driver
```

**UPDATE**:

I found that the problem is with the package `flutter_map_tile_caching` (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map_tile_caching).

When I call

```
await FMTC.instance('mapStore').manage.createAsync();
```

I get this error.

Comment: It seems that the issue is related to `Isar`. Try to upgrade its dependency, by making sure you are using the latest version of the Isar package in your pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: I don't use Isar package. It isn't in pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: yes, demo app work

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue as you 2 days ago. As I dug into the dependencies, I found out that Flutter added the Prerelease version 9.0.0-dev.2 of FMTC since I was using flutter_map 5.0.0.

If it is your case, either step down to Flutter_map 4 and use FMTC 8, either wait for FMTC to handle flutter_map 5 (or propose them a PR on github if you find out the problem ;-) )